# How to distribute android library which are dependent on each other using Jitpack?

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-libraries, android-library, jitpack

How to Distribute Interdependent Modules in Jitpack for Open-Source Project (Clean Architecture)
Context:

We're working on an open-source project built with Clean Architecture and a multi-module approach. We need to distribute the modules separately using Jitpack. Here's our project structure:

project 
├── app 
├── buildSrc 
├── Core 
├── core_ui 
├── auth 
├── settings 
└── ...other modules

**buildSrc** has all the dependencies that are included in each module.
Core and core_ui contain essential components and reusable UI elements, respectively. Other modules like auth and settings depend on these.

Questions:

How to distribute the modules in jitpack or any other similar package manager.
Should we create a separate repo for each module? If so how to do that?

Additional Information:

I did follow [this](https://vtsen.hashnode.dev/how-to-publish-android-library-on-jitpackio-with-github) for distributing the library and was able to distribute a single library but there isn't any info regarding distributing libraries which are dependent on each other.